# Codeigniter dbutil throwing unsupported error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, database-backups

This is my controller function to backup my database

```
function backupSystem(){
// Load the DB utility class
$this->load->dbutil();
$prefs = array(
'format' => 'zip',
'filename' => 'mybackup.zip', 
'add_drop' => TRUE, 
'add_insert' => TRUE, 
);
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 
// Load the file helper and write the file to your server
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file("<?php echo base_url();?>/backup_db/mybackup.zip", $backup);
}
```

Here backup_db is the folder i created to store result which is in the same location where application lies

Running the controller throws me this kind of errors

> **A Database Error Occured**
>
> Unsupported feature of the database platform you are using.
>   Filename:D:\xampp\htdocs\scholarship\system\database\mysqli\mysqli_utility.php

Line Number:82

This project has an older version of codeigniter being used. Is it the older version does not support backup. Also need suggestion is it the best way to backup database because as per the documentation does not recommend to backup larger database with it .

Answer (score 0):

According to Codeigniter [guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html):

Change

```
'filename' => 'mybackup.zip'
```

To This

```
'filename' => 'mybackup.sql',
```

Comment: Yes its kind of solved the problem now am stock in it

Comment: if(write_file($filename, $backup,'r+')){
            echo "successfully writter";
        } this aint working now where  $filename=base_url().'/downloads/'.date('d-m-Y').'.sql'; and $backup is the output of the dbutil

Comment: not able to write to a file now ,print_r() displays the sql i need but write_file not working now may be its a permission problem

Comment: i tried to changed the readonly property of directory by right clicking on the directory i want but now working